# MooTools Slider doesn't work when adding to DOM after creation

Tags: javascript, slider, mootools

I'm having a lot of problems with getting the MooTools Slider (http://mootools.net/docs/more/Drag/Slider) to work. After a lot of debugging, it seems that the problem lies in the fact that i create the slider (by doing new Slider(sliderElement, knobElement)) before adding it to the dom. When i create the slider afterwards it works fine, but doing it this forces me to create the sliders in a *very* illogical location in my code

What i'd like to do is this:

```
createSlider: function()
{
    var sliderContainer = new Element('div');   
    var sliderTrack = new Element('div', {class: 'slider_track'});
    var sliderKnob = new Element('div', {class: 'slider_knob'});
    sliderTrack.grab(sliderKnob);

    new Slider(sliderTrack, sliderKnob);

    slidersContainer.grab(sliderTrack);

    return sliderContainer;
}
```

Is there any way to get it to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the slider in the code from the start and hide it with CSS until it is enabled?

Comment: Because they are generated on the fly, the user can add something to the document that has sliders.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing a reference of target container to your function, then first add the required elements to it, then construct the slider.